# Linux disk usage graphical statistic tools like WinStatDir

Tags: linux, disk-space

Is there a tool like [WinStatDir](http://windirstat.info/) that can present a graphical stats of disk uage? Showing folders/files in different size of rectangles by its disk usage. Looks like Mac has similar drive visualization tool too. (see [this](http://metalbabble.com/technobabble/?p=91))

Comment: What version of Linux are you using? Ubuntu has built in software that does this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Baobab](http://www.marzocca.net/linux/baobab/) uses arc segments instead of rectangles.

Comment: Baobab also has a View as Treemap option that shows rectangles. Gdmap also provides a rectangular display.

Answer (score 1):

There's also [kdirstat](http://kdirstat.sourceforge.net/) (called k4dirstat in KDE4).